# Split column in POLARS DF from the right

Tags: python, python-polars

im new to Polars DF and python and looking a way to split my location column into 3. In pandas i can choose the split ( left or right ) but Polars seems to split from the left. My Location contains spaces and not ','.
Pandas:  `df[["City State", "Zip"]] = df["Location"].str.rsplit(" ", n=1, expand=True)` and then City, State o split in to two.
If i do split in Polars:

```
(df.select(pl.col('Location').str.split_exact(' ',2)))
```

I get this:
"Chicago", "IL","60007"
"La","Mirada","CA"
Cali is missing a zip.
How can i choose a split side ?
Thank You.

Tried to look for split from sides but not successful.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a good way to do a right-to-left split in polars directly.

You could use regex instead though.

Suppose you have

```
df=pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("a", ['Chicago IL 60007', 'La Mirada CA 90637'], dtype=pl.Utf8),
    ]
)
```

then you can do

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        loc=pl.col('a').str.extract_groups(r"(.+?) ([A-Z]{2}) (\d{5})")
                        .struct.rename_fields(['City','State','Zip'])
                        )
    .unnest('loc')
    )
shape: (2, 4)
┌────────────────────┬───────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ a                  ┆ City      ┆ State ┆ Zip   │
│ ---                ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str                ┆ str       ┆ str   ┆ str   │
╞════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ Chicago IL 60007   ┆ Chicago   ┆ IL    ┆ 60007 │
│ La Mirada CA 90637 ┆ La Mirada ┆ CA    ┆ 90637 │
└────────────────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

This assumes you always have 5 digit zip codes and that your state codes are always 2 capital letters. There are a ton of address validating regex resources out there than can help refine this to your needs. Just be careful as this uses the [rust regex crate](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#examples) rather than python's `re` module so some of the syntax will be different.

**Alternatively**, since converting to and from arrow is copy-free you could use pyarrow's [`split_pattern`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.split_pattern.html) which has a reverse parameter like this:

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
    loc=pl.from_arrow(pc.split_pattern(df['a'].to_arrow(), " ", max_splits=2, reverse=True))
        .list.to_struct()
        .struct.rename_fields(['City','State','Zip'])
        )
    .unnest('loc')
    )
shape: (2, 4)
┌────────────────────┬───────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ a                  ┆ City      ┆ State ┆ Zip   │
│ ---                ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str                ┆ str       ┆ str   ┆ str   │
╞════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ Chicago IL 60007   ┆ Chicago   ┆ IL    ┆ 60007 │
│ La Mirada CA 90637 ┆ La Mirada ┆ CA    ┆ 90637 │
└────────────────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────┘
```